# In Docker (for Windows) How can I add registry entries in bulk while building my image?

Tags: windows, docker, registry

I'm using Docker for Windows and building the docker image with a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mydockerhublogin/win2k16-ruby:1.0

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app


# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

RUN powershell -Command \
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
  New-Item "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\ExampleCom" -Force ; \
  New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\ExampleCom" -Name MenuLastUpdate -Value "test" -Force

RUN powershell -Command \
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
  New-Item "HKLM:\Software\ExampleCom" -Force ; \
  New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\ExampleCom" -Name MenuLastUpdate -Value "test" -Force
# Run ruby script when the container launches
CMD ["C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe", "docker_ruby_test.rb"]
```

Note that I am adding some registry entries to the Windows registry which the code inside the container will access. While this method of adding registry entries is fine for a few entries, my requirement is to add dozens of entries required for my windows application. Is there a way to do this in a more concise manner?

Comment: Try creating a file for the your registry entry and copy that inside the container. Then try running `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {regedit /i /s C:\shared\settings.reg}`

Comment: @tarunlalwani, Yes. That worked!

Answer (score 8):

Try creating a file for the your registry entry and copy that inside the container.

Then try running `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {regedit /i /s C:\shared\settings.reg}`

Comment: Thank you so much. We have a working post launch script that utilizes New-Item and New-ItemProperty. The Dockerfile specifies to copy this script into the container. Logs say that all lines within the script executed successfully. The registry keys and values were never added though. This was driving me nuts. I was about to test using this solution: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e718a560-2908-4b91-ad42-d392e7f8f1ad/take-ownership-of-a-registry-key-and-change-permissions?forum=winserverpowershell  Thankfully your solution worked! I hope everyone finds this.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the only way I could getting working using `4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

```
COPY Registry/ChromeConfiguration.reg .

RUN reg import ChromeConfiguration.reg
```